PHP script fails to redirect user
I have a HTML form which, when submitted, redirects the user to a PHP script. The script should process the form and redirect the user to home.html, but instead of being redirected the browser displays a blank page. The two files (.php and .html) are in the same directory.
Code description
HTML form — The HTML form is designed to collect user data like name, email, password, etc. Once submitted, it sends the data by POST redirection to the PHP script procesare_formular.php.
PHP Script (procesare_formular.php) — This script processes the form and checks for errors. It then attempts to redirect the user to home.html using HTTP header Location: home.html.
Problem
Instead of being redirected to home.html, the browser shows a blank page. The form is processed, but no redirection occurs.
What I’ve tried / checked
The PHP script is in the same directory as home.html, so the problem isn't one of mislocation.
I’ve ensured the script exits immediately after the header() function is called.
Nothing is echoed before the header() call, as I make sure to send the header before writing any response body.
The code
HTML form:
<form method="post" action="procesare_formular.php">
    <div>
        <label for="nume">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="nume" id="nume" placeholder="Enter name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="prenume">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="prenume" id="prenume" placeholder="Enter surname" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="telefon">Phone</label>
        <input type="tel" name="telefon" id="telefon" placeholder="Enter phone number" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="confirmparola">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="confirmparola" id="confirmparola" placeholder="Confirm password" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submitregister" value="Create account">
</form>

PHP script:
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==="POST")
    {
        $nume = trim($_POST['nume']);
        $prenume = trim($_POST['prenume']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $confirmparola = trim($_POST['confirmparola']);
        $telefon = trim($_POST['telefon']);
        $mesaje = [];
        
        // Check if all fields are filled
        if(empty($nume) || empty($prenume) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($confirmparola) || empty($telefon))
        {
            $mesaje[] = "All fields must be filled!";
        }
        
        // Check if passwords match
        if($password !== $confirmparola)
        {
            $mesaje[] = "Password must be typed exactly the same twice for confirmation";
        }
        
        // Check if password is strong enough
        if(strlen($password) <= 5 || $password == "password")
        {
            $mesaje[] = "Password must be longer than five characters";
        }
        
        // If there are errors, display them
        if(!empty($mesaje))
        {
            echo "<h3>Errors:</h3><ul>";
            foreach($mesaje as $mesaj)
            {
                echo "<li>$mesaj </li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            exit;
        }
        
        // Redirect to the home page if no errors
        header("Location:home.html");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Request is not valid.";
    }
?>


It's highly probable that you are getting an error, but the debugging settings are not showing it to you. Check the server logs. Do you see errors in the server log file?

I checked logs but i see [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 1ms ] 405
Method Not Allowed
VersiuneHTTP/1.1 something like this i dont know why. i use visual studio code with live server.

I just tested it and if your php script is in this action file procesare_formular.php then I am properly being redirected to that location home.html

You mentioned using VS Code's Live Server, but Live Server is typically just a simple static file server and doesn’t support executing PHP scripts. In other words, it only serves static files like .html, .css, and .js directly to the browser, but .php files are not actually executed by a proper PHP engine (such as Apache + PHP or Nginx + PHP-FPM). When you encounter a "405 Method Not Allowed" error, it indicates that the server does not allow you to use POST to access .php files because, to the server, they are treated as static files.

You can create a simple PHP file that echoes something to test whether PHP files are executing properly.

Use the code below. You have an error in the $mesaje array.
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==="POST")
{
    $nume = trim($_POST['nume']);
    $prenume = trim($_POST['prenume']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $confirmparola = trim($_POST['confirmparola']);
    $telefon = trim($_POST['telefon']);
    $mesaje = [];
    
    // Check if all fields are filled
    if(empty($nume) || empty($prenume) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($confirmparola) || empty($telefon))
    {
        $mesaje[] = "All fields must be filled!";
    }
    
    // Check if passwords match
    if($password !== $confirmparola)
    {
        $mesaje[] = "Password must be typed exactly the same twice for confirmation";    
    }
    
    // Check if password is strong enough
    if(strlen($password) <= 5 || $password == "password")
    {
        $mesaje[] = "Password must be longer than five characters";
    }
    
    // If there are errors, display them
    if(count($mesaje) > 0)
    {
        echo "<h3>Errors:</h3><ul>";
        foreach($mesaje as $mesaj)
        {
            echo "<li>$mesaj </li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        exit;
    }

    // Redirect to the home page if no errors
    header("Location:home.html");
    exit;
}   
else
{
    echo "Request is not valid.";
}
?>  


You should really explain to the OP what their mistake was, and exactly what correction you've made, not just ask them to blindly accept your version of the code. See also [answer]. :-)

@ADyson, already mentioned You have an error in the $mesaje array.

Yes I know. But that's really vague, which I think you must realise. What kind of "error"? Where? What did you do to fix it? You have enough reputation points to know what a useful answer looks like.

As far as I can see, the only change you've made is if(count($mesaje) > 0), which makes no functional difference whatsoever. Did you test your answer before posting it? I am now wondering if you didn't properly explain what you'd changed because you don't actually have a rational reason for making that change (after all, naturally, such a rationale would come from an understanding of what effect the change would have on the operation of the code...and in this case there is no effect).
